# Groovy JsonSlurper and Maps with (Sub) Objects

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to marshal and unmarshal a groovy bean. I am using the functionality later on in Java. The idea is I am marshalling the object using the JsonOutput and unmarshal it with the JsonSlurper. My bean includes a map of sub objects.

The problem is, that JsonSlurper is unmarshalling the values of the map to a LazyMap and not to the original object. If I include the object directly the unmarshalling works.

Here an example of what I am doing...

```
import java.util.Map

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class ClassA {

    ClassB subClass

    Map<String, ClassB> subClasses = [:]

    static def ClassA build(String json){
        new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
    }

    def String toString() {
        JsonOutput.toJson(this)
    }
}
```

...and ClassB...

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

class ClassB {

    String message = [:]

    def String toString() {
        JsonOutput.toJson(this)
    }
}
```

...and here the Java code that fails...

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
ClassB classB = new ClassB();
classB.setMessage("Hello World!");
classA.setSubClass(classB);
classA.getSubClasses().put("First", classB);

System.out.println(ClassA.build(classA.toString()).getSubClass().getMessage());
System.out.println(ClassA.build(classA.toString()).getSubClasses().get("First").getMessage());
```

...the second last line prints "Hello World!", as expected but the last line fails with...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap cannot be cast to ClassB
```

Is there a (better) way to marshal and unmarshal a groovy object to json?

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson does the trick and works reliable...

ClassA

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

class ClassA {

    ClassB subClass

    Map<String, ClassB> subClasses = [:]

    static def ClassA build(String json){
        new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, ClassA.class)
    }

    def String toString() {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
        try {
            new ObjectMapper().writeValue(writer, this)
            return writer.toString()
        }
        finally {
            writer.close()
        }
    }
}
```

And ClassB

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

class ClassB {

    String message = [:]

    def String toString() {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
        try {
            new ObjectMapper().writeValue(writer, this)
            return writer.toString()
        }
        finally {
            writer.close()
        }
    }
}
```